# Im stuck on java programing

Tags: java, bluej

i need to write method for the website class, called browserLogin, which allows a browser who already has an ID to log in to the site. This method is passed a Browser object as a parameter and which uses the browser's setLoginStatus method to "log in" that browser to the website. It also needs to outputs a welcome message to a terminal window in the format
Wine Direct welcomes browser 6732, you are now logged in.

```
private int yearOfBirth;
private int id;
private String email;
private boolean loggedIn = true;

public Browser(String getEmail, int getId, int getYearOfBirth)
{
    email = getEmail;
    id = getId;
    yearOfBirth = getYearOfBirth;
}

public Browser()
{
    email = "J.Booth@winedirect.com";
    id = 2678;
    yearOfBirth = 1990;
    loggedIn = true;
}

public void yearOfBirth(int getYearOfBirth)
/**
 * 
 */
{
   yearOfBirth = getYearOfBirth; 
}

public void id(int getId)
/**
 * 
 */
{
    id = getId;
}

public void setLoginStatus()
{
    if(loggedIn = true)
    {
        System.out.println("online;" + id);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Offline");
    }
}

public boolean isLoginStatus()
/**
 * 
 */
{
    return loggedIn;
}

public void email(String getEmail)
/**
 * 
 */
{
    email = getEmail;
    loggedIn = true;
}

public void loggedOut()
/**
 * 
 */
{
    email = "";
    yearOfBirth = 0;
    id = 0;
    loggedIn = false;
}
```

}

```
public class Website

// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private int hits;
private int salesTotal;
private Browser loggedIn;

private void browserLogin()
/**
 * 
 */
{
    loggedIn 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide some code or prepare for a bad time..

Answer (score 2):

Okay so let's start by writing your specifications into java code:

`browserLogin method is passed a Browser object as a parameter`

Your method doesn't have any parameters, so add it:

```
private void browserLogin(Browser br){

}
```

`uses the browser's setLoginStatus method to "log in" that browser to the website`

You specifically say to use the method, .. but the method is quite wrong.

```
 if(loggedIn = true)
```

What this piece of code does is that it makes loggedIn true and then returns the value of loggedIn (which will always be true). Probably you meant:

```
if(loggedIn == true)
```

However it is not a setter method in any way. So assuming you want to log browser in, when it's not already logged in you could do something along these lines:

```
private void browserLogin(Browser br){
    if(!br.isLoginStatus()){          
      br.setLoginStatus(true);
    }         
}
```

and edit your method to this:

```
public void setLoginStatus(boolean value)
{
    loggedIn = value;

    if(loggedIn == true)
    {
        System.out.println("online;" + id);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Offline");
    }
}
```

From what I see, you just starting with Java. I would suggest reading the oracle tutorials and starting really from the beginning: [Oracle Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html)

Comment: +1 but fighting an urge to put spaces after `if` and before `{` ;)

Comment: when i try and put this code

private void browserLogin(Browser br){
if(!br.isLoginStatus()){
  loggedIn = br;
  br.setLoggedIn(true);
}         
}

into my website class, it say cannot find symbol, method setLoggedIn(boolean)

do i need to set it as boolean??

Comment: @user3018998 yeah what it says is that there is no method "setLoggedIn with boolean as a paramater".. which is correct because I meant to write setLoginStatus. See edited answer.

Comment: I think you can remove `loggedIn = br;` (which doesn't make sense anyway) and just call `br.setLoginStatus(true);`.

Comment: @AdamV that's correct! It was written before setLoginStatus method was edited..