# cannot find symbol error in java code

Tags: java

i need to write method for the website class, called browserLogin, which allows a browser who already has an ID to log in to the site. This method is passed a Browser object as a parameter and which uses the browser's setLoginStatus method to "log in" that browser to the website. It also needs to outputs a welcome message to a terminal window in the format Wine Direct welcomes browser 6732, you are now logged in.

this is the code i have so far with help, but not when i put the code. ive put this code in
the website class:

```
private void browserLogin(Browser br){
    if(!br.isLoginStatus()){
      loggedIn = br;
      br.setLoggedIn(true);
    }       
}
```

but its shows a message "cannot find symbol, method setLoggedIn(boolean)"
and this is my browser code:

```
private int yearOfBirth;
private int id;
private String email;
private boolean loggedIn = true;

public Browser(String getEmail, int getId, int getYearOfBirth)
{
    email = getEmail;
    id = getId;
    yearOfBirth = getYearOfBirth;
}

public Browser()
{
    email = "J.Booth@winedirect.com";
    id = 2678;
    yearOfBirth = 1990;
    loggedIn = true;
}

public void yearOfBirth(int getYearOfBirth)
/**
 * 
 */
{
   yearOfBirth = getYearOfBirth; 
}

public void id(int getId)
/**
 * 
 */
{
    id = getId;
}

public void setLoginStatus(boolean value)
{
   loggedIn = value;

if(loggedIn == true)
{
    System.out.println("online;" + id);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Offline");
}
}

public boolean isLoginStatus()
/**
 * 
 */
{
    return loggedIn;
}

public void email(String getEmail)
/**
 * 
 */
{
    email = getEmail;
    loggedIn = true;
}

public void loggedOut()
/**
 * 
 */
{
    email = "";
    yearOfBirth = 0;
    id = 0;
    loggedIn = false;
}
```

Comment: Putting a more explicit title in your question would increase the probability to get a useful answer and would help future visitors that may encounter the same issue.

Comment: cannot find symbol mean that the method is not defined, you should declare one inside Browser class in order to use it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Im stuck on java programing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130055/im-stuck-on-java-programing)

Comment: cannot find symbol, method setLoggedIn(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the method `setLoggedIn(boolean)` in your `Browser` class, hence the error. I think you want to use `setLoginStatus(boolean value)` instead, as it seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this makes perfect sense. Here's the method you have defined in Browser

```
public void setLoginStatus(boolean value)
{
  ....
}
```

Yet you are calling: `br.setLoggedIn(true);`
Notice the difference in method names. Refactor the method names so that they match

Answer (score 0):

The error ( "cannot find symbol, method setLoggedIn(boolean)") is telling you that your Browser class doesn't have a method defined named "setLoggedIn" - which is correct.  Change the call to be br.setLoginStatus(true).